# System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed context instance. with SaveChangesAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I have two controllers, one that handles a product and the other handles reporting of this product.
both of them needs to save to the database, one modifies or adds a product and the second keeps track of the changes.

the first controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PutCustomer(int id, Customer customer)
{
    if (id != customer.Id)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    var existCustomer = _context.Customer.Where(x => x.FNumber == customer.FNumber).FirstOrDefault();
    //existCustomer.LastModifiedBy = HttpContext.GetIISServerVariable("LOGON_USER");
    existCustomer.LastModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
    var oldFeatures = existCustomer.Features.Split(",");
    var newFeatures = customer.Features.Split(",");
    var  featuresRemoved = oldFeatures.Except(newFeatures);
    var featuresAdded = newFeatures.Except(oldFeatures);
    existCustomer.Features = customer.Features;
    _context.Entry(existCustomer).State = EntityState.Modified;
    
    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!CustomerExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    addReport(existCustomer, featuresRemoved, featuresAdded);

    return NoContent();
}
```

addReport basically creates the report object and calls PostReport.

and the second controller cold:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Report>> PostReport(Report report)
{
    _context.Report.Add(report);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetReport", new { id = report.Id }, report);
}
```

but when it returns to the PostReport I am getting an error that the context was disposed of.

One solution online was to use `SaveChangesAsync()`, but I already use that.

Any solutions please ?
Thank you

Comment: What does CustomerExists code look like? Could you share all of the relevant controller code? Or provide a minimal repro?

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek It's edited now

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I am still missing the CustomerExists method from your posting, called within the catch block. On similar note, what does addReport code look like? What I'm looking for is a missing await somewhere. And an async continuation that runs after the controller has exited and the DbContext is disposed. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Could you also post the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: How are you getting the context ? From Dependency Injection?

Comment: If you are working with dependency injection you need to register your db context as Scoped (AddScoped) - set the value for contextLifetime to ServiceLifetime.Scoped.

Comment: This is all the information in the exception:
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.

Comment: @jeb, yes I am.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek ```private bool CustomerExists(int id)
{
    return (_context.Customer?.Any(e => e.Id == id)).GetValueOrDefault();
}```
 this is the code of that function.

Comment: @PaulNakitare is that in the controller when I am injecting ?

Comment: @Alaa you set this in the AddDbContext: DbContextOptions. See this link for more information https://haacked.com/archive/2023/01/09/scoping-db-context-copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by changing the `SaveChangesAsync` to `SaveChanges` in the second controller.

Comment: If I may say so, this is not an adequate resolution. This means you end up denying your application the benefits of asynchronous communication in the transmission of your data to your persistent framework.